# Why do we need extensions in azure VM?

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-role

when we can manually connect to remote desktop and install software we desire, why we need extensions? Custom Script extension and Desired State configuration works same way. They run the same powershell script. why do we need many extension that basically does same thing. Please give me an idea on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when we can manually connect to remote desktop and install software we
>   desire, why we need extensions?

You can connect to remote desktop to install software, but sometimes if you can't connect to it, you can use custom script extension to install it, or change some configuration.

For example, if you can't RDP to windows VM(RDP service disabled), you can use custom script extension to enable it.

Custom extension will use wagent to run this script.

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT thank you so much your answer. It helped me in understanding reason for extensions. I am new to azure VM

Answer (score 0):

Main reason to use those - automation. How would you connect to 10000vms and install same software? What time would it take you? How many errors will you make?

This question is basically asking - what is the purpose of automation? we can do the same thing manually. Well, good luck with that :)

Comment: your explanation gave me an idea of need of automation in VM. thank you for replying